# How can I write if-else conditions in cypress according to element's value?

Tags: if-statement, cypress, cypress-conditional-testing

[image]How can I run this function, according to the value change of element with if-condition?

```js
 assertSwitch(){
    
            cy.get('[data-test="form-switch"]').invoke('attr','value').then(($switchOnOff) =>{
                
            if($switchOnOff == true){
                    cy.isContain('.item-undefined-switch[data-test="item-undefined-email"]', 'true')
            }else{
                    cy.isContain('.item-undefined-switch[data-test="item-undefined-email"]', 'false')
                }
            })
        }
```

Comment: I don't quite understand what you're asking. You want to take the value of the `[data-test="form-switch"]` element and assert on the `[data-test="item-undefined-email"]` element?

Comment: It would help if you could add the `isContain()` custom command code.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is both switches have the same `data-test`, so Cypress starts to get confused

```js
cy.get('[data-test="form-switch"]')
  .eq(0)                              // pick one
  .invoke('attr','aria-checked')      // this attr indicates checked state
  .then(($switchOnOff) => {
                
    if($switchOnOff === 'true') {  // note adjustments here

      cy.isContain('.item-undefined-switch[data-test="item-undefined-email"]', 'true')  
    } else {
      cy.isContain('.item-undefined-switch[data-test="item-undefined-email"]', 'false')
    }
})
```

Or all switches

```js
cy.get('[data-test="form-switch"]')
  .each(($switchOnOff) => {
    const value = $switchOnOff.attr('aria-checked')
    cy.isContain('.item-undefined-switch[data-test="item-undefined-email"]', value)  
})
```

Comment: First script always enters in else part.                                                                                     Second script result:  expected '<p.item-undefined-switch>' to contain undefined

Comment: It's because the ant-d switch doesn't set value when toggled. You can use `aria-checked` or class `ant-switch-checked` - both change of toggle.

Comment: the same results for both.

Comment: You should double-check, it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```js
cy.get('[data-test="form-switch"]').then(($ele) => {
  if ($ele.attr('val') == 'true') {
    cy.get('button[data-test="form-switch-input"]').should(
      'have.attr',
      'aria-checked',
      'true'
    )
    //Add something here
  } else {
    cy.get('button[data-test="form-switch-input"]').should(
      'have.attr',
      'aria-checked',
      'false'
    )
    //Add something here
  }
})
```

Comment: I tried, but says: "Timed out retrying after 4000ms: expected '<div.ant-row.ant-form-item.form-switch>' to have attribute 'aria-checked'"